# Upload size limit

Tags: box-api

I tried to upload big files to box.net (box.com) with API.
I see that there is upload size limit . For me it is 100MB.
If i upload file with size exactly 100MB (104860224 bytes) then file is not accepted. If less then upload works.

I wanted to ask if this limit is the same for all box.net users or it can differ depending on account package?

Is there a way to get upload limit with API? before i s art file upload i would like to check if this size will be accepted or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For upload limit, use this:

```
curl https://api.box.com/2.0/users/10543463 \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN"
```

See: https://docs.box.com/reference#users

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of different file-size limits, depending upon the type of Box account you sign up for:  https://www.box.com/pricing/